# Integration by parts for distributions (generalized function)

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

The following question comes from a research paper. I have simplified some statements and backgrounds.

For any smooth compactly supported scalar function $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$ defined on $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^2,$ and given a first of operator $L=\partial_t+\partial_x$, we denote its adjoint operator is $L^*=-\partial_t-\partial_x$, the classical integration by parts told us that
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  Lu \cdot v \ dx dt=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  u \cdot L^*v \ dx dt+\int_{\mathbb{R}} (uv)|_{t=t_2}dx-\int_{\mathbb{R}} (uv)|_{t=t_1}dx.
$$
Now I am stating some properties we have already deduced. If $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2), Lu \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ ($Lu$ is understood as a distribution), then for any $t_0 \in \mathbb{R},$ we have $u|_{t=t_0} \in H^{-1/2}(\mathbb{R})$ and the following estimate holds
$$
\| u|_{t=t_0}\|_{H^{-1/2}(\mathbb{R})} \leq C(\| u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}+\| Lu \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}).
$$
Moreover, $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (compactly supported functions) are dense in $\{(u,Lu): u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2),Lu \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2) \}$ with respect to the graph norm $\| u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}+\| Lu\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}.$

Hence, for $u,Lu \in L^2$, we know that there is a sequence of functions $u_n \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ so that $u_n,L u_n$ converge to $u,Lu$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2),$ and $u_n|_{t=t_0}$ converges to $u|_{t=t_0}$ in $H^{-1/2}(\mathbb{R})$ for any $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}.$

Clearly, for any compactly supported function $v$ and $u_n,$ the classical integration by parts formula holds:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  Lu_n \cdot v dt&=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  u_n \cdot L^*v dt+\int_{\mathbb{R}} (u_nv)|_{t=t_2}dx-\int_{\mathbb{R}} (u_nv)|_{t=t_1}dx \\
&=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  u_n \cdot L^*v dt+\langle u_n|_{t=t_2},v|_{t=t_2}\rangle_{\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D}}-\langle u_n|_{t=t_1},v|_{t=t_1}\rangle_{\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D}}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The paper said that if we let $n\rightarrow +\infty$, then we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  Lu \cdot v dt=-\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  u \cdot L^*v dt+\langle u|_{t=t_2-},v|_{t=t_2}\rangle_{\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D}}-\langle u|_{t=t_1+},v|_{t=t_1}\rangle_{\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D}}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I am confused about the strict meaning of $u|_{t=t_1+}$ and $u|_{t=t_2-}$ as distribution here. It looks like the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral, but I don't know how to deduce the expression. Can anyone help me? Any references are welcomed.

Comment: Suggestion: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>` for the pairings. That looks better: $\langle u, v \rangle$ vs $<u, v>$.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question.

Comment: It is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space. $(H^{-1/2}(\mathbb{R}), H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R}))$-duality is obtained from 
$(\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D})$-duality by completion of ${\mathcal{D}}$

Comment: @dsh I have read the wiki page and other books (like Gelfand's book) about rigged Hilbert space, but I did't find the statement that "$(H^{-1/2},H^{1/2})$ duality is obtained from the $(\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D})$ by completion of $\mathcal{D}$." Could you elucidate your idea? I don't know how the statement can help me with understanding my question. I still don't know the exact meaning of $u|_{t=t_2-}$ (the rational of well-defined of jump in the common integral).

Comment: Can your question be reformulated as "Is $u|_{t=t_2-}\in H^{-1/2}(\mathbb{R})$ Radon measure or is it distributions of order > 0?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals specify all Radon measure, or distributions of order 0. If $u|_{t=t_2-}$ were Radon measure, then setting $v=0$ near $t_1,$ one would need:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  Lu \cdot v dt
-\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{\mathbb{R}}  u \cdot L^*v dt
=\langle u|_{t=t_2-},v|_{t=t_2}\rangle_{\mathcal{D}',\mathcal{D}} \le C_K(u)\|v|_{t=t_2}\|_{K,\infty}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
for some $C_K(u) > 0$ for every compact $K$ on $t=t_2,$ $\|v|_{t=t_2}\|_{K,\infty}=\sup_{x\in K}|v|_{t=t_2}(x)|.$ To check only smooth $u,$ one would require $C_K(u)$ to be bounded as functions of $\|u\|_2 + \|Lu\|_2.$

If one can provide estimation of $\int_K |u(x, t_2)|\:dx$ for smooth $u$ with compact support and compact $K$ uniformly using norm $\|u\|_2 + \|Lu\|_2,$ then assumption re. Radon measure is correct. It seems like $\int_K |u(x, t_2)|\:dx$ can be estimated as $(\int_K 1\:dx)\|Lu\|$ integrating along $x+t=const.$

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I have been reading some material about Radon measure in order to understand your answer, though I haven't fully understood yet. Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.

Comment: The plan is straight forward (1) the condition for continuity of measure as linear functional on functions with compact support, (2) consider set of such measures (depending on $u$) and (3) reduce to dense subset (smooth $u$ with compact support) of such measures in the quasi-complete space of measures. The principal part is to get estimation (last sentence).

Comment: Could you recommend some books for me to understand the details, like "L-S integrals specify all Radon measure"?

Comment: This equivalence is rather specific and only for 1-dimensional case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248063/functions-of-bounded-variation-as-the-dual-of-ca-b (need to consider locally bounded variation to extend to the whole line from interval). Dover edition of Taylor's "General theory of functions and integration" contains a proof. Order of distributions can be found in Treves "Topological vector spaces, distributions.." Bourbaki's Integration exposes Radon measures as linear functionals on functions with compact support (ch. 3).

Comment: Thank you so much!